# Problem with installing VBox guest additions in 13.10 (shared folders)

Tags: 13.10, virtualbox, guest-additions

I am using 13.10 for both the host and guest. The host has the guest additions iso. While installing the guest additions, I encounter an error when trying to compile the shared files module. The relevant log file /var/log/vboxadd-install.log shows the following:

```
 gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.dirops.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include  -I/usr/src/linux-he
aders-3.11.0-12-generic/arch/x86/include -Iarch/x86/include/generated  -Iinclude -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-gene
ric/arch/x86/include/uapi -Iarch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/include/uapi -Iin
clude/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KER
NEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declar
ation -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -m64 -mno-sse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mtune=generic
 -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -fstack-protector -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONF
IG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_A
S_AVX2=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -Wframe
-larger-than=1024 -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -pg -mfentry -DCC_USI
NG_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -fsho
rt-wchar -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/VBoxGuestMangling.h -I/lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbo
x.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxsf/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxsf/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/vb
oxsf/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HGCM -DIN_MODU
LE -DIN_GUEST_R0 -DRT_NO_EXPORT_SYMBOL -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS  -DMODULE  -D"KBUILD_STR(s)=#s" -D"KBU
ILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(dirops)"  -D"KBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(vboxsf)" -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_dirops.o /tmp/vbox.0/diro
ps.c
/tmp/vbox.0/dirops.c:292:5: error: unknown field ‘readdir’ specified in initializer
     .readdir = sf_dir_read,
     ^
```

I believe this may be relevant to https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=56954. Has anyone else encountered the same issue and is there a simple fix around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. On my side, the host is WindowsXP and the guest is Ubuntu 13.10.  I was upgrading the guest from 13.04 to 13.10 and at the same time, I've upgraded VirtualBox from 4.2 to 4.3 (in the host).

I was trying to compile the Guest Extensions with

```
/etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
```

without success.

Then, I tried from the new Virtualbox ISO:

```
sudo /media/x/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.2_90405/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

It works :-)

I don't know how you tried to compile the guest additions, but maybe trying from the ISO will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here, on Saucy 13.10 with VirtualBox 4.2.16 as available in the Software Center... fixed it by (first removing Ubuntu's outdated version) and then installing a 4.3.6 downloaded directly from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads.

Comment: It seems there are a number of compatibility issues between the 3.11 kernel and virtualbox version < 4.3.2. Another one I ran into is http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=727222. I hope these things will get fixed in the repository when the recent version gets integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of the VirtualBox iso here http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/

OR automatically download it with this command

```
version=$(wget -qO- http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/LATEST.TXT)&& wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/$version/VBoxGuestAdditions_$version.iso
```

Using the newest iso worked for me.